# Rails 5 Faraday connection for Facebook Omniauth

Tags: ruby, facebook, devise, omniauth, ruby-on-rails-5

I have tried all the tricks in the book and all the possible solution in stack over flow.But still couldn't figure out the problem. The program pauses at the call back initiated stage and shows `faraday connection : timed out`. I have the following code:

```
gem 'omniauth', '~> 1.3', '>= 1.3.1'
gem 'omniauth-facebook'
```

Routes.rb

```
devise_for :users, 
:path => '', 
:path_names => {:sign_in => 'login', :sign_out => 'logout',             :edit => 'profile' },
:controllers => {:omniauth_callbacks => 'omniauth_callbacks'}
```

/Controller.rb

```
class OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController
  def facebook
    @user = User.from_omniauth(request.env["omniauth.auth"])
    if @user.persisted? 
      sign_in_and_redirect @user, :event => :authentication
      set_flash_message(:notice, :success, :kind => "Facebook") if is_navigational_format?
    else
      session["devise.facebook_data"] = request.env["omniauth.auth"].except("extra")
      redirect_to new_user_registration_url
    end
  end
end
```

/user.rb

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  def self.from_omniauth(auth)
    user = User.where(email: auth.info.email).first
    if user
      return user
    else
      where(provider: auth.provider, uid: auth.uid).first_or_create do |user|
        user.provider = auth.provider
        user.uid = auth.uid
        user.email = auth.info.email
        user.image = auth.info.image
        user.password = Devise.friendly_token[0,20]
        user.firstname = auth.info.first_name
        user.lastname = auth.info.last_name
        user.phonenumber == '0000000000'
        user.tc == true
        user.year == true
      end
    end
  end
end
```

/devise.rb

```
config.omniauth:facebook,ENV['FACEBOOK_ID'],ENV['FACEBOOK_SECRET'],scope:'email',info_fields:'email,first_name,last_name'
```

Comment: Did you find a solution?